# Is it possible to mix migrations file without harmful consequences?

Tags: rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-4

Let me explain :

I followed the [M. Hartl tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=4.0) and I did just like him with migrations. So now, I have the followings files in my db/migrate directory (I spare you the timestamps):

**create_users.rb**

```rb
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**add_index_to_users_email.rb**

```rb
class AddIndexToUsersEmail < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :users, :email, unique: true
  end
end
```

**add_password_digest_to_users.rb**

```rb
class AddPasswordDigestToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :password_digest, :string
  end
end
```

**add_remember_token_to_users.rb**

```rb
class AddRememberTokenToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :remember_token, :string
    add_index :users, :remember_token
  end
end
```

**add_admin_to_users.rb**

```rb
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

Is it possible to mix everything into **create_users.rb** like following, and delete the others migration files without any damage to my app ?

**create_users.rb**

```rb
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest
      t.string :remember_token
      t.boolean :admin, default: false

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :users, :email, unique: true
    add_index :users, :remember_token
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. A straighforward strategy for that might be:

1. In order to avoid data loss, make a database dumb (create a DB backup)
2. Drop and recreate the database:

   ```
   rake db:drop db:create
   ```
3. Have all migrations merged into a single file like you've shown
4. Run:

   ```
   rake db:migrate
   ```
5. Restore the DB backup

Though, this may become tricky if you already have the application deployed on production.

Comment: Sometimes useful if you delete schema.rb before rake db:migrate. Basically rake db:migrate is generate a nice new schema.rb. Especially if you modify your fields and database structure in your migrations files.